# Как передать POST запрос?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <textarea class="ctrlSubmit"></textarea>
</form>

<script>
  var t = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
  var i = 0;

  while(t[i]) {
    if(/ctrlSubmit/.test(t[i].className)) {
      t[i].onkeyup = function(e) {
        e = window.event || e;

        if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey){
          // alert(this.value);
          this.form.submit();
        }
      }
    }
    ++i;
  }
</script>
```

Страничка `test.php`:

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['????'];

print_r($data);
```

Вопрос с каким именем передает форму. Что подставить вместо `????`?

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` и можно выяснить что подставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не поставили имя передаваемого c формы поля `<textarea class="ctrlSubmit" name="desc"></textarea>` и в php `$data=$_POST['desc'];`